# What are the available files for $BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR?

Tags: android, github, bitrise

I am starting to use **Github Release** on my Bitrise account. In one of the steps, it asks me to choose which files it wants me to upload to the Github release:

[image]

I searched everywhere for the available files I can upload, but I had no success. What are those available files?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Github Release but it seems that they ask you which artifact(s) you want to deploy. Meaning the artifacts that you have generated during build.

Comment: You can check available enviroment variables in here: https://devcenter.bitrise.io/builds/available-environment-variables/